# ReadOnly attribute does not work on TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, attributes

I'm converting from `VS2003` to `VS2005` and as a part of a conversion, I need to change the way we are currently setting `ReadOnly` attribute for `textbox` controls.

We had the following code before:

```
private void EnableHistory(bool state)
{
  TextBox itbNewHistory = UltraWebTab1.FindControl("tbNewHistory") as TextBox;

  if( itbNewHistory != null )
  {
     itbNewHistory.Enabled = state;                                       
     itbNewHistory.ReadOnly = ! state;
  }
}
```

New code is:

```
private void EnableHistory(bool state)
{
    TextBox itbNewHistory = UltraWebTab1.FindControl("tbNewHistory") as TextBox;

    if( itbNewHistory != null )
    {
        itbNewHistory.Enabled = state;
        string hSwitch = Convert.ToString(!state);
        itbNewHistory.Attributes["readonly"] = hSwitch;                                
     }
}
```

Also, I removed `ReadOnly = "true"` attribute from `asp.aspx` code

With a new code, the `ReadOnly` property is always `true`.

Why does it happen and how can I fix it.

Thank you

Comment: WHY IN THE WORLD would you be converting from 2003 to 2005?  Both are no longer supported, and you should at the very least move to 2012, 2013 would be better.  Why go through this effort only to have to do it again in a couple of years?

Comment: Well, it is not the question to me. I do not make decisions, I just change the code

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it is always readonly is because of the way HTML works.

In HTML, merely the presence of the "readonly" (or "disabled) attribute makes it readonly, even if it says `readonly="false"`, it will still be readonly because the readonly attribute is present.

If you don't want it readonly, then you have to remove the attribute if it's present, or don't add it if it's not.  Also, the actual value of the readonly attribute should be readonly like so:  `readonly="readonly"` not true or false.

```
itbNewHistory.Attributes.Remove("readonly");
if(state)
    itbNewHistory.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

Comment: Sorry, in my brain I swapped readonly and disabled.. they work the same though in html, merely the presence of the attributes causes them to be true.

Answer (score 0):

try the following may it helps

```
rohSolutions.Attributes.Remove("ReadOnly");
itbNewHistory.Attributes.Add("ReadOnly", hSwitch.ToString());
```

Comment: "Try this and see if it works" answers can get a bit of a pass if they happen to be right, but otherwise they're often frowned on as being basically comments.